# regex : how to eliminiate urls ending with .dtd

Tags: regex

This is JavaScript regex.

```
regex = /(http:\/\/[^\s]*)/g;

text = "I have http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd and I like http://google.com a lot";

matches = text.match(regex);

console.log(matches);
```

I get both the urls in the result. However I want to eliminate all the urls ending with .dtd . How do I do that?

Note that I am saying ending with .dtd should be removed. It means a url like http://a.dtd.google.com should pass .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nicest way to do it is to use a negative lookbehind (in languages that support them):

```
/(?>http:\/\/[^\s]*)(?<!\.dtd)/g
```

The `?>` in the first bracket makes it an atomic grouping which stops the regex engine backtracking - so it'll match the full URL as it does now, and if/when the next part fails it won't try going back and matching less.

The `(<!\.dtd)` is a negative lookbehind, which only matches if `\.dtd` *doesn't* match ending at that position (i.e., the URL doesn't end in `.dtd`).

For languages that don't (such as JavaScript), you can do a negative lookahead instead, which is a bit more ugly and is generally less efficient:

```
/(http:\/\/(?![^\s]*\.dtd\b)[^\s]*)/g
```

Will match `http://`, then scan ahead to make sure it doesn't end in `.dtd`, then backtrack and scan forward again to get the actual match.

As always, http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good reference for more information

Comment: Hmm. It's possible JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds then. In that case, I can't think of a nice way you can do it with a single regexp - your best bet is just to use what you have now, loop through the results and manually remove any that end in ".dtd".

Comment: I know JavaScript does not support look behind. However it does support positive and negative lookahead.

Comment: Or maybe there is: `/(http:\/\/(?![^\s]*\.dtd\b)[^\s]*)/g`. It's not as nice or efficient as the look-behind one, but seems to do the trick.